# How can I control my recent posts of Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

```
  <section id="article">
  <h3>Recent posts</h3>
<ul>
    {% for post in site.posts %}
      <li>&raquo; <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</section>
```

This is my codes for all articles, how can I control the number of posts, and just show 10 posts in the section?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the way to do it.

```
   {% for post in site.posts offset: 0 limit: 10  %}
```

Comment: Hi, do you know why my url of this post contains a `%5c` and couldn't be open rightly. [wrong url](http://hypergroups.github.io/mathematica%5Cmath-experiment/2013/09/11/Math_Experiment-Limit) which you can open it from my home page, and the html file is [here](https://github.com/HyperGroups/hypergroups.github.com/blob/master/_posts/Mathematica/Math-Experiment/2013-09-11-Math_Experiment-Limit.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
<section id="article">
  <h3>Recent posts</h3>
  <ul>
    {% for post in site.posts limit:10 %}
      <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</section>
```

Try this one. This code show 10 most recent post like recent post widget.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about it another way.

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:1  %}
{% if forloop.last %}
  <li>
    <a href="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  </li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I've included an if logic tag with a forloop.last so it would only display the last, most recent post. The output would only be one post since I've also included { limit:1 }.